# TinyMCE: No agrega contenido a textarea creado dinámicamente

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Estoy implementando a un panel de control un sistema de agregar comentarios, (Agregar, editar, borrar comentarios), cuando el usuario quiere editar su comentario se crea un textarea con tinyMCE para poder editar su texto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no aparece el texto en el textarea, este es mi código jquery con el que creo el textarea y paso la información.

```
$(document).on('click', '#listNotes #btnN .edit a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  /* Act on the event */

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var url = URL_P + '/panel/getNotaUnica'

         $("#listNotes #btnN").toggle('slow').hide();
         $("#listNotes #"+ id + " .timeline-body #content-nota").html('<form></form>');
         $("#listNotes #"+ id + " .timeline-body #content-nota form").attr({
           action: URL_P +'/panel/editNota',
           method: 'POST',
           id: 'validate-changeNota'
         });
         $("#listNotes #"+ id + " .timeline-body #content-nota form").append('<textarea id="edit" name="nota" data-validate="text">' )
          loadTinymce()
          $("#listNotes #"+ id + " .timeline-body #content-nota form").append('<input type="hidden" value=' + id + ' name = "idNota" >')
         $("#listNotes #"+ id + " .timeline-body #content-nota form").append('<input type="submit" value="Guardar Cambios" class="btn btn-sm green accent-4 white-text mt-3" disabled> ')
         $("#listNotes #"+ id + " .timeline-body #content-nota form").append('<input type="button" value="cancelar" class="btn btn-sm btn-secundary mt-3" id="CEN" data-id="' + id + '"> ')


          AjaxData(url, {id: id}, function(error, response){
            if(error == null)
              {
                tinymce.EditorManager.get('edit').setContent(response.nota)
              }
          })
});
```

AjaxData es una función que e creado que devuelve un callback (lo e configurado con **async: false**)

```
function AjaxData(url, data, callback)
  {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
    })
    .done(function(res) {
      callback(null, res)
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      callback(error)
    })
  }
```

Lo curioso es que cuando el usuario presiona cancelar y vuelve a presionar editar, ya aparece el texto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que es debido a la forma asincrona como se crea el elemento. He buscado un metodo en tinyMCE para resolver esto y no lo encuentro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser por el estado en que está al cargar la página, prueba a ver si tiene valor y en caso negativo modifica directamente el valor del textarea.

```
var editor = tinymce.EditorManager.get('edit');
if (editor !== null) {
   editor.setContent(response.nota);
} else {
   $(#edit).val(response.nota);
}
```

Origen [aquí](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/284818).

Answer (score 0):

ami me funcionó solo colocando la información del value como cualquier HTML

```
<textarea name="texto"  id="editor1"><?php echo $row2["texto"];?></textarea>
```